# How can I display world hillshade and a shapefile without losing original colors and hillshade details?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, overlay, hillshade

This is what I am trying to do, but I am using the World Hillshade file from ArcGIS online and a land status shapefile:

http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0312/learn-a-new-method-for-displaying-hillshades-and-elevation-tints.html

I am fairly new to GIS, so I do not think I am asking google the correct questions. I basically want to overlay my land status shapefile over the world hillshade, but the only way I know how to display both is by changing the transparency on one or the other. This article seems like it will give me what I want.

I have started by creating a mosaic dataset. The only way I can think of proceeding is to somehow convert the world hillshade and the land status to raster so I can add it to the mosaic dataset, but I do not believe that is possible and now I am stuck... There is a lot I am missing to the conceptual side of GIS.

Is the world hillshade something that I want? What about a DEM, should I be using that instead? I do not really understand the difference between the two or if that even matters.... all I want is for my map to have nice mountainous features with the land status color on top, both unaltered.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.

Comment: Why are you making a mosaic dataset?